# Rails helper for a nested member of a has_many through is routing incorrectly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, has-many-through

I have a has_many :through relationship where feed has_many lists.

Routes

```
resources :feeds do
  member do 
    resources :feed_lists
  end
end
```

Route I'm trying to hit:

```
feed_list
   DELETE /feeds/:id/feed_lists/:id(.:format)   feed_lists#destroy
```

Then when looping through @feed.lists I get incorrect paths:

```
feed_list_path(list, @feed) = "/feeds/41/feed_lists/41"
feed_list_path(@feed, list) = "/feeds/5/feed_lists/5"
feed_list_path [@feed, list] = "/feeds/41/5/feed_lists/41/5
```

Obviously what I want is

```
feed_list_path(list, @feed) = "/feeds/41/feed_lists/5"
```

Is this not possible with a has_many :through relationship ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes should look more like this:

```
resources :feeds do
  resources :lists
end
```

The clue that it's a routing problem is in the route that was generated; both of the parameters are called `id`, so the same value is put into the URL twice.  The correctly generated route should be `feeds/:feed_id/lists/:id` (note the different parameters: `feed_id` and `id`).

You should now be able to do:

```
feed_list_path(list, @feed)  # => "/feeds/41/lists/5"
feed_list_url(list, @feed)   # => "http://yoursite/feeds/41/lists/5"
url_for [@feed, list]        # => "http://yoursite/feeds/41/lists/5"
```

See the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more information.

Comment: Yup, this works. That feed_id/_id thing makes sense. Although I had to leave it as resources :feed_lists not just :lists or it would redirect routes back to the actual :lists controller.